# Apps besides ClipChamp to merge videos and automatically upload to YouTube

Tags: video, video-editing, youtube, app

ClipChamp has been glitchy for me, and I'm looking for another app to serve my purposes. Specifically, I'm looking for a free app that can merge multiple videos together and then automatically upload the final product to YouTube. I'm not looking for an app that requires me to manually upload the final product; rather, I'm looking for a way to both merge and automatically upload to YouTube.

Besides Clipchamp, do any free apps exist that can take multiple videos, merge them, and then automatically upload them to YouTube?